Angular Agrid Delete Sede
've tried to add a button delete on my aggrid tabel, but when i click on it, none method was called, why ?
I've tried to do a lot of test,
put the column definition on my html, but doesn't work, also i've tried to change the way to define the delet colomun like remove ICellRendererAngularComp, and tried without, but i've got the same result, the method not was call. I also using an IA like CODY or phind, but i've receive a solution.
Please help me, i'm a bakcend debeloper and i need to resolve this problem
My ts :
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { AgGridAngular } from 'ag-grid-angular';
import { ColDef, ColumnApi, GridApi, ICellRendererParams, ValueGetterParams } from 'ag-grid-community';
import { SediEsterneService } from '../action/sedi-esterne.action';
import { SediEsterne } from '../interface/interface.sedi-esterne';
import { SedEsterneAggiunSedeComponent } from '../sedi-esterne-aggiun-sede/sedi-esterne-aggiun-sede.component';
import { ICellRendererAngularComp } from 'ag-grid-angular';

import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';

@Component({
  selector: 'sedi-esterne',
  standalone: true, // Mantieni standalone: true
  imports: [AgGridAngular, MatButtonModule],
  templateUrl: './sedi-esterne.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sedi-esterne.component.scss']
})
export class SediEsterneComponent implements OnInit, ICellRendererAngularComp {
  private params: any;
  gridApi: any;
  gridColumnApi: any;

  defaultColDef = {
    filter: true, // Abilita il filtro per tutte le colonne
    sortable: true, // Abilita l'ordinamento per tutte le colonne
    resizable: true // Abilita la ridimensionabilità delle colonne
  };
  columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
    {
      headerName: "Azione",
      field: "azione",
      cellRenderer: this.removeRowRenderer.bind(this),
      pinned: 'left'
    },
    {
      headerName: "Sede",
      field: "sede",
      pinned: 'left',
      sortable: true, // Abilita l'ordinamento
      filter: true,   // Abilita il filtro
      editable: true

    },
    {
      headerName: "Indirizzo",
      field: "indirizzo",
      sortable: true, // Abilita l'ordinamento
      filter: true,   // Abilita il filtro
      editable: true
    },
    {
      headerName: "Tipo",
      field: "tipo",
      sortable: true, // Abilita l'ordinamento
      filter: true,   // Abilita il filtro
      editable: true
    },
    {
      headerName: "NetSede23",
      field: "netSede23",
      sortable: true, // Abilita l'ordinamento
      filter: true,   // Abilita il filtro
      editable: true
    },
    {
      headerName: "IpOutsideFirewall29",
      field: "ipOutsideFirewall29",
      sortable: true, // Abilita l'ordinamento
      filter: true,   // Abilita il filtro
      editable: true
    },
    {
      headerName: "Firewall",
      field: "firewall",
      sortable: true, // Abilita l'ordinamento
      filter: true,   // Abilita il filtro
      editable: true
    },
    {
      headerName: "CitrixMgmt",
      field: "citrixMgmt",
      sortable: true, // Abilita l'ordinamento
      filter: true,   // Abilita il filtro
      editable: true
    },
    {
      headerName: "IpCitrixIntPri",
      field: "ipCitrixIntPri",
      sortable: true, // Abilita l'ordinamento
      filter: true,   // Abilita il filtro
      editable: true
    },
    {
      headerName: "IpCpePri",
      field: "ipCpePri",
      sortable: true, // Abilita l'ordinamento
      filter: true,   // Abilita il filtro
      editable: true
    },
    {
      headerName: "LaPri",
      field: "laPri",
      sortable: true, // Abilita l'ordinamento
      filter: true,   // Abilita il filtro
      editable: true
    },
    {
      headerName: "TipologiaCollPri",
      field: "tipologiaCollPri",
      sortable: true, // Abilita l'ordinamento
      filter: true,   // Abilita il filtro
      editable: true
    },
    {
      headerName: "IpCitrixIntSec28",
      field: "ipCitrixIntSec28",
      sortable: true, // Abilita l'ordinamento
      filter: true,   // Abilita il filtro
      editable: true
    },
    {
      headerName: "IpCpeSec",
      field: "ipCpeSec",
      sortable: true, // Abilita l'ordinamento
      filter: true,   // Abilita il filtro
      editable: true
    },
    {
      headerName: "LaSec",
      field: "laSec",
      sortable: true, // Abilita l'ordinamento
      filter: true,   // Abilita il filtro
      editable: true
    },
    {
      headerName: "TipologiaCollSec",
      field: "tipologiaCollSec",
      sortable: true, // Abilita l'ordinamento
      filter: true,   // Abilita il filtro
      editable: true
    },
    {
      headerName: "IpCitrixIntTer28",
      field: "ipCitrixIntTer28",
      sortable: true, // Abilita l'ordinamento
      filter: true,   // Abilita il filtro
      editable: true
    },
    {
      headerName: "IpCpeTer",
      field: "ipCpeTer",
      sortable: true, // Abilita l'ordinamento
      filter: true,   // Abilita il filtro
      editable: true
    },
    {
      headerName: "LaTer",
      field: "laTer",
      sortable: true, // Abilita l'ordinamento
      filter: true,   // Abilita il filtro
      editable: true
    },
    {
      headerName: "TipologiaCollTer",
      field: "tipologiaCollTer",
      sortable: true, // Abilita l'ordinamento
      filter: true,   // Abilita il filtro
      editable: true
    },
    {
      headerName: "DataMigr",
      field: "dataMigr",
      sortable: true, // Abilita l'ordinamento
      filter: true,   // Abilita il filtro
      editable: true
    },
    {
      headerName: "Referenti",
      field: "referenti",
      sortable: true, // Abilita l'ordinamento
      filter: true,   // Abilita il filtro
      editable: true
    },
    {
      headerName: "Note",
      field: "note",
      sortable: true, // Abilita l'ordinamento
      filter: true,   // Abilita il filtro
      editable: true
    },
    {
      headerName: "UpgPri",
      field: "upgPri",
      sortable: true, // Abilita l'ordinamento
      filter: true,   // Abilita il filtro
      editable: true
    },
    {
      headerName: "UpgSec",
      field: "upgSec",
      sortable: true, // Abilita l'ordinamento
      filter: true,   // Abilita il filtro
      editable: true
    },
    {
      headerName: "CitrixSn",
      field: "citrixSn",
      sortable: true, // Abilita l'ordinamento
      filter: true,   // Abilita il filtro
      editable: true
    },
    {
      headerName: "CitrixLicHostId",
      field: "citrixLicHostId",
      sortable: true, // Abilita l'ordinamento
      filter: true,   // Abilita il filtro
      editable: true
    },
  ];


  rowData!: SediEsterne[];

  constructor(private sediEsterneService: SediEsterneService) { }
  agInit(params: ICellRendererParams): void {
    this.params = params;
  }

  refresh(params: ICellRendererParams): boolean {
    this.params = params;
    return true; // Restituisci true per ridisegnare il componente
  }

  onGridReady(params: { api: GridApi; columnApi: ColumnApi }): void {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
    console.log("api", params.api);
    console.log("column api", params.columnApi);
  }


  onCellEditingStopped(event: any): void {
    console.log('Valore della cella modificata:', event.data);
  }

  // O utilizza onRowEditingStopped per ottenere tutti i dati della riga modificata
  onRowEditingStopped(event: any): void {
    console.log('Dati della riga modificata:', event.data);
    const sedeDaModificare = event.data;
    this.sediEsterneService.editSede(sedeDaModificare).subscribe({
      next: (success) => {
        console.log('Aggiornamento completato con successo:', success);
        // Qui puoi aggiungere qualsiasi azione successiva, come aggiornare la UI
      },
      error: (error) => {
        console.error('Si è verificato un errore durante l\'aggiornamento:', error);
        // Gestisci l'errore, ad esempio mostrando un messaggio all'utente
      }
    });
  }

  @ViewChild(AgGridAngular) agGrid!: AgGridAngular;

  removeRowRenderer(params: any) {
    return `<button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="removeRow(${params.rowIndex})">Elimina</button>`;

  }

  removeRow(rowIndex: number): void {
    const res = confirm(`Sei sicuro di voler eliminare questa riga?`);
    if (res) {
      const rowNode = this.gridApi.getRowNode(rowIndex);
      if (rowNode) {
        this.gridApi.applyTransaction({ remove: [rowNode.data] });
      }
    }
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sediEsterneService.fetchGetSedi().subscribe({
      next: (data) => {
        this.rowData = data;
      },
      error: (err) => {
        console.error('Errore nella chiamata API', err);
      }
    });
  }

}

My HTML :
<ag-grid-angular
  class="ag-theme-alpine"
  [rowData]="rowData"
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
  style="height: 100vh;"
  [domLayout]="'autoHeight'"
  [editType]="'fullRow'"
  [defaultColDef]="{ resizable: true }"
  [pagination]="true"
  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
  
  (rowEditingStopped)="onRowEditingStopped($event)"
  [paginationPageSize]="25">


</ag-grid-angular>


